# Complex Analysis: Log Function

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analyticity

I want to approach this problem with maximum understanding of everything that is going on.

I have the function $F(z)=\log(z^2+4)$, and I want to give a region in which it is analytic. I guess I shouldn't call it a function until I give the region since it's multivalued.

$(1)$ I first start by solving $z^2+4=0 \Rightarrow z^2=-4$. (why do we do this)?

$(2)$ Then, I define $z=re^{i\theta} \Rightarrow r^2e^{2\theta i}=-4$

$(3)$ Thus, $r=2$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi + 2\pi k}{2}$ for $k=0,1$.

$(4)$ Next, I draw the rays eminating from the $0's$ of the function (green).

$(5)$ These are the two rays describing 2 complex numbers such that when I double their angle and add $4$ I end up on the negative x-axis.

$(6)$ Now I choose my region of validity. I take my branch cut to be principle branch of log, which seems intuitive.

However, can I also choose to make $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ \ {$z=re^{i\theta}: r>2, \theta=\frac{pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$}?

[image]

Comment: Foe step $(1)$, you do that to find the branch points of $\log(z^2+4)$.

Comment: Nice. And the ray is considered the branch?

Comment: Then you need to make the branch cut. Make sure you get the idea by studying the simpler function $\ln(z)$. Note that the branch cut is not unique. Note also that, $z=0$ is not a branch point for $\log(z^2+4)$.

Comment: Yes I understand that in the simple log function one can choose the branch cut to be any ray extending from the origin to infinity. This is because the choice of angle is ambiguous because one can add $2\pi$ and get another solution even though you are back in the same place.

Comment: Note that, you can take the cut $[-i,i]$.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial point to remember about a branch cut is that it is chosen to ensure that inside the remaining domain of definition of the function, it must be impossible to find a small curve which "winds around" a branch point.

For the straightforward $\log z$ function, then, as you know, it is enough to take any ray emanating from $0$, and this will prevent any "winding".

In your example, we have two branch points; one at $2i$ and one at $-2i$.

We can avoid any possibility of this winding problem by defining branch cuts as follows:

Take 2 branch cuts, one going from $2i$ to infinity (say upwards along the imaginary axis), and the other going from $-2i$ towards infinity (say downwards along the negative imaginary axis). This ensures the domain is now simply connected with no possibility of winding round a branch point.

The alternative possible approach of taking a single branch cut going directly from $2i$ to $-2i$ does not work, since in this case we have a branch point at infinity. This alternative choice of branch cut would work however in the case of the function $\sqrt{z^2+4}$ which just has two finite branch points.